# async call with reducer not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

i'm trying to implementing a **Redux action** that retrieves some **json** data with an asynchronous call using **React Native**. I put the function **fetchRestaurant()** everywhere inside component but i still get this error:

**Cannot read property 'type of undefined**.

here's the code inside **action/restaurant.js**

```
export function setFetchedRestaurant(restaurants){
  return   Object.assign({ type: types.SET_FETCHED_RESTAURANT, restaurants:restaurants } );
}



export function fetchRestaurant(){
  var restaurants;
  fetch('https://appetizing.000webhostapp.com/connect.php').then((response) => response.text()).then((responseText) => { dispatch(setFetchedRestaurant(JSON.parse(responseText)));}).catch((error) => {console.warn(error);});

}
```

and this is my call to **fetchRestaurant() function** inside my component:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.fetchRestaurant();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use middleware to handle the asynchronous action. One such middleware is Redux thunk.

Here is your action creator written as a Redux thunk:

```
export function fetchRestaurant() {
    return (dispatch) => {
       var restaurants
       fetch('https://appetizing.000webhostapp.com/connect.php')
          .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseText) => {
              dispatch(setFetchedRestaurant(JSON.parse(responseText)));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
               console.warn(error);
            });

    }
}
```

**redux-thunk**

Remember for this to work you will to insert redux-thunk into your middleware chain when configuring your Redux store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

**How does a Thunk Action creator work?**

This single thunk action creator is an action creator that will be handled by our redux thunk middleware since it fits the signature associated with thunk action creators, that is it returns a function.

When store.dispatch is called our actions will go through the middleware chain before they reach the store. Redux Thunk is a piece of middleware that will see our action is a function and then give this function access to the stores dispatch and get state.

Here is the code inside Redux thunk that does this:

```
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
}
```

Okay so that is why our thunk action creator returns a function. because this function will be called by middleware and give us access to dispatch and get state meaning we can dispatch further actions at a later date.

Remember redux-thunk is not the only solution. if we wanted to dispatch promises instead of functions we could use redux-promise. However I would recommend starting with redux-thunk as this is the simplest solution.

**redux-promise**

An alternative method to redux thunk for handling your async Redux actions is redux-promise. Instead of action creators that return a function you can dispatch action creators that return a promise.

Here is an example:

```
function actionExample(payload){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(data); 
    });
}
```

You can of course combine redux-promise and redux-thunk middleware so that you can dispatch functions that when called dispatch promises

Comment: the error was solved but if i print the response with **console.log(response.text);** is different from the real response

Comment: Okay what about if you console.log(response)? That should give you the whole response object right?

Comment: Okay where are you printing the response? Can you show me the code that is doing this? Remember you only have access to the response object inside the .then function which is chained to the promise.  Secondly I am using the 'isomorphic-fetch' library so when fetch is called in my code a promise is returned. What does fetch call in your code? Apart from that you may not be calling your action directly instead of calling it with store.dispatch(). Failing that you haven't configured your store with redux-thunk.

Comment: i used [this call](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/network.html) and works,thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. I am happy to help.